# If derivate of one is bigger always, then distance of two points is always bigger than other?

Tags: calculus

So lets start, I am sure that it'll come out as freaking easy. But I guess I'm burned out.

*Question:* $f,g: [a,b] \longrightarrow\mathbb R$

Both $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and both of them is differentiable on $(a,b)$

If $|f'(x)|\ge |g'(x)| > 0$ for every $x\in (a,b)$, then show that $|f(x) - f(y)| \ge |g(x) - g(y)|$ for every $x,y\in (a,b)$.

Note: This is not an homework or somewhat question. I have final in two days and I am solving non-graded problem sets.

Comment: You need $x \gt y$ for the statement to be true.  What "does both functions are defined same" mean?  In the title it should be derivative

Comment: @RossMillikan  I corrected it, sometimes I say things like I'm talking in daily life. I am sorry. However, why do we need that inequality of x and y?

Comment: I had forgotten the absolute value bars and thought the difference would be negative.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from the fact that derivatives are nonzero, we may expect that it is always positive or negative, so that we can drop the absolute value. This is indeed the case, by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). If there are two points that the derivatives have different signs, there will be another point with derivative $0$.

Then you can drop the absolute values, and we may assume both $f'$ and $g'$ are positive(therefore, each $f, g$ are increasing). Can you deduce from here?

Comment: So, I think that from Mean Value Theorem, we can say that there is a $f'(k)$ that holds for k in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(k)$ = ( $f(x)$- $f(y)$ ) / $x$ - $y$. And does the same thing for $g$ for let us say point $m$ in $(a,b)$. Then for both of these equations, x-y is constant, therefore we can omit that. And you know the rest. Is it correct?

Comment: In your reasoning, what is missing is that $k$ and $m$ are not necessarily the same. Then you cannot use the inequality for $f'$ and $g'$. Instead, how can you tackle this?

Comment: I mean, $f'(k)$ must be greater than $g'(m)$ due to assumption at the very beginning. Then, if you replace the derivative inequality's terms with the definition of them (i.e. for function $f'(x)$ you can replace it as $f'(k)$ which is actually $ ( $f(x)$ - $f(y)$) / $x$ - $y$ ) $ . Therefore, you can do the same for g, call it m.

Comment: But I think that's not what you written in the assumption. According to your writing, we only know that $f'(x)\ge g'(x)$ for $x\in(a, b)$. It does not hold for different $k$ and $m$.

Comment: We are taking the MVT interval as $(x,y)$ assuming they are not equal. Then, we can delete $x-y$'s in the left and right handsides because they are not zero. You only have $f(x) - f(y)$ on the left and $g(x) - f(y)$ on the right which is the asked statement.

Comment: I know, I solved a bit too fast. But I believe I got the idea. Super thanks!

Comment: Umm,,, but just in case that you have mistaken, I note one thing. You cannot say that $f'(k)\ge g'(m)$ for arbitrary $k, m$, and it is possible only when $k=m$. So what you need to do is to apply MVT for $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$. Then $h'(x)\ge 0$ so $h$ is monotone increasing, which meas $f-g$ is monotone increasing and $f(y)-f(x)\ge g(y)-g(x)$ for $y>x$.

Comment: Uh. Thank you again...

Answer (score 0):

Since $(\forall x)g'(x)\neq 0$,then $(\forall x,y)g(x)-g(y)\neq 0.$ Thus, by **Cauchy mean value theorem**, there exists a $x\gtrless \xi \gtrless y$ such that

$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{g(x)-g(y)}\right|=\left|\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}\right|\ge1,$$which is what you want.